# Integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+5x)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I was trying to solve the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+5x)^2}dx $$

where $t$ is an arbitrary constant but I can´t quite grasp it. I was trying to implemment Feynman´s trick here, perhaps when expanding: $(1+xt)^2 = 1 + (xt)^2 + 2xt$ and considering a new parameter $\alpha$ on $e^{-x^2}$ but I didn´t get anywhere, nor am I sure if it can even be done that way.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Doesn't Feynmann's trick require bounds on your integral?

Comment: So if $t$ can be any number (say 4), how do we know that the anti derivative can be found (in terms of elementary functions?).

Comment: Im not sure, Im just trying to find a way to solve this.

Comment: Can you provide context (and/or source)?

Comment: Does the integral have limits?

Comment: The method of differentiation under the integral sign (that it is called "Feynman's trick" is one of the unfortunate effects of the internet) is a method of computing *definite* integrals. Moreover, it is inconceivable that you could get a simple formula for the indefinite integral you ask about in terms of $t$ and $x$, because if you *did* then setting $t = 0$ would produce a simple formula for $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$ and that is known to be impossible (no elementary antiderivative). Therefore your task is totally hopeless.

Comment: The integral does not have limits, but I will edit the question and give a specific value for $t$.

Comment: Mathematica gives $I_t = \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{t^2}} \left(2 \pi  \text{erfi}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-2\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+\ln \left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)-\ln \left(t^2\right)+4 \ln (t)\right)+2 t \left(t-\sqrt{\pi }\right)}{2 t^3}$. For the case of $t=5$ we have $\frac{1}{125} \left(\sqrt{\pi } \left(2F\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)-5\right)\frac{\text{Ei}\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)}{\sqrt[25]{e}}+25\right)$. Where $F$ denotes the complex Dawson function and $\text{Ei}$ is the exponential integral function, and $\text{erfi}$ is the imaginary error function. Laplace transforms can be used.

Answer (score 1):

We can write
$$\frac{e^{-x^2}}{(1+t x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  (-1)^n \frac{(n+1)}{t^{n+2}}\,\,\frac{ e^{-x^2}} { x^{n+2}}$$
$$\int  \frac{ e^{-x^2}} { x^{n+2}}\,dx=\frac 12 \int e^{-y} y^{-\frac{n+3}{2}}\,dy=-\frac 12\Gamma \left(-\frac{n+1}{2},y\right)=-\frac 12\Gamma \left(-\frac{n+1}{2},x^2\right)$$ which is far to be elementary.

Comment: In the incomplete Gamma function, aren´t we suposed to have a positive value for $\left(-\frac{n+1}{2} \right)$ in order for it to be well defined? How does that extra minus sign compensate for it?

Comment: Also, why did you use the upper incomplete Gamma function?

Comment: One can write, with positive a, Γ(-a,z)= One can write, with positive a, Γ(-a,z)=$\mathrm{E_{a+1}(z) z^{-a}=\int_z^\infty \frac{x^{-a-1}}{e^x}dx}$ with the Exponential Integral function which then has a positive argument.